# Does WPF really needs UserControl?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

I'm really don't know why [**UserControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.UserControl(v=vs.110).aspx) exists. MSDN article says about one:

> Provides a simple way to create a control.

It adds two useless layers into the [VisualTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391(v=vs.110).aspx) - **UserControl** and ContentPresenter. If you apply the filter on MSDN article about it to hide **Inherited** and **Protected** members, you will see nothing!

When you see to the content, that is added to the [**UserControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.UserControl(v=vs.110).aspx), you usually see the following:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
    ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

or

```
<UserControl ...>
    <DockPanel>
    ...
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

So, you can avoid using [**UserControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.UserControl(v=vs.110).aspx) just using the layer you have added inside that:

```
<Grid ...>
...
</Grid>
```

or

```
<DockPanel ...>
...
</DockPanel>
```

and inherit the control from the class you are using as the root element in your **xaml**.

**Q:** So I wonder - which profit we get using the [**UserControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.UserControl(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing really, to be honest**. In my years creating custom controls for WPF, I never used a UserControl.

If you are creating your own custom control you use `ContentControl` or anything that is more suitable to derive from. **You want to avoid additional UI elements** in the `Visual Tree` as it can affect your application performance. However, if you are a beginner

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A UserControl is a ContentControl, which means that it can contain a
>   single object of any type (such as a string, an image, or a panel).
>   For more information, see the ContentControl class.
>
> If you do need to create a new control, the simplest way is to create a class that derives from UserControl. Before you do so, consider that your control will not support templates and therefore will not support complex customization. However, deriving from UserControl is a suitable model if you want to build your control by adding existing elements to it, similar to how you build an application, and if you do not need to support complex customization. (If you want to use templates with your control, derive from Control instead.)

Comment: I have 3.5 years experience with WPF, and all I know is that UserControl add one level for UI Automation Tree, too. So I'm totaly agree with you

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using a `UserControl` is to easily encapsulate some .NET controls along with some functionality into a reusable control. While you could just repeat the XAML that is inside a `UserControl` wherever you need it (like you suggested), it is far simpler to add on `UserControl` instead of many .NET controls.

Then you have to think about making changes to the `UserControl`... without using a `UserControl`, you'd have to find everywhere that you used your standard .NET controls (instead of using a `UserControl`) and update them all. It's much easier to update just the `UserControl`.

Furthermore, creating a `UserControl` is far quicker and simpler than creating a `CustomControl`... for a start, you need to create a `CustomControlLibrary` project and define your `CustomControl` in `generic.xaml` with no direct code behind.

Additionally, declaring `UserControl`s are absolutely perfect for defining views when using the MVVM development methodology.

Finally, let's hear from Microsoft... from the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

[image]

Personally, I don't know what I'd do without `UserControl`s, but each developer will have their own opinion... this answer is just mine.

Comment: I have suggested to use reusable custom controls, that inherited from the control you need - not from UserControl. You do not need UserControl - in most cases you need some panel. So create a class, inherit it from that panel, and use it where you need, like UserControl, but without UserControl involved.

Answer (score -1):

One of the profits is that you can create a custom control which will you use in different places.

Comment: You are allowed to use the method I have describe - just inherit from the control you really need - and use it anywhere you want